# Why are only 3 paragraphs appended?

Tags: d3.js

I am a beginner to d3. I read that when one binds a data set of $n$ entities to an element, calls enter, and then performs operations, those operations will be performed $n$ times.

However, here, my paragraph is only appended 3 times even though the size of my data set is 4:
http://jsfiddle.net/johnhoffman/tYr5U/

```
d3.select("body").data([1, 2, 3, 4]).enter().append("p").text("g");
```

Output:

```
g
g
g
```

Why just 3 times?

Answer (score 4):

Here's the code I suspect you want to use.

```
d3.select("body").selectAll("p").data([1,2,3,4]).enter().append("p").text("g");
```

The join should be done with the "p" elements, not the "body" element.

As to why it has three in your example:

The data has four elements, being bound to the single "body" element. By default, the first element, 1, is bound to the existing body (defined in HTML). The remaining 3 elements are bound to non-existing "body" elements. Since "enter()" is only called for non-existing elements, the append operation gets called three times on the root of the DOM.

To demonstrate this, try:

```
d3.select("body").data([1,2,3,4]).enter().append("p").text(function(d) {return d;});
```

And you will see the number in the data being appended, instead of g.

Confusing, but the [Circles Tutorial](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/tutorial/circle.html) helped me understand this.